# How to rollback exec

Tags: sql, exec, rollback

I have the simple stored procedure which is to delete the current data and input the new data. If the input  is failed, I want to keep the old data. I tried to use the following code but the old data always been deleted even the errorfilename is generated with error. The execution always returns 0 and say successful.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMyTable] 
    @FileName varchar(200),
    @errorFileName varchar(300),
AS

BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN Transaction T


        Delete FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
        DBCC CHECKIDENT('MyTable',RESEED,0)


        Declare @sql varchar(max)
        set @sql = '
            BULK INSERT MyTable
            From ''' + @FileName + ''' 
            WITH
            (
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                ERRORFILE = ''' + @errorFileName + '''
             )'

         EXEC (@sql)
       COMMIT TRANSACTION T
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T
    END CATCH
END
```

Update the problem:  I use sql express and management studio 2012. Looks like the EXEC put the error into error file and no error was caught outside.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link answers your question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/8556acc9-79ce-4fd7-9210-50452a6920f6/begin-transaction-within-try-catch-or-vice-versa

Comment: I put the 'try' on the outside of 'transaction', doesn't work either.